# c# Abstract class with non abstract method throw ReflectionTypeLoadException

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, abstract

i have a problem with an abstract class with non abstract method when i'm using Reflection.

Below an example of my classes :

```
abstract class ClassA
{
    public abstract void Method1();

    protected void Method2()
    {
        //Some logic here....
    } 
}

class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public override void Method1()
    {
        //Method1 implementation
    }
}
```

I'm using reflection to get child classes implementing a specific class (ClassA in my Example)

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("MyAssembly"))
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => p.IsClass &&  p.IsSubclassOf(ClassA)).ToList();
```

On the "s.GetTypes()" call, .Net throw a "System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException" saying that ClassB not implements Method2 (that is not abstract).

Any Idea ?

Comment: Can you show the real code? `p.IsSubclassOf(ClassA)` won't compile. When I change it to `p.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClassA))`, it compiles and runs without any exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed. It was another library that cause the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use typeof before classA, see example:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("MyAssembly"))
            .SelectMany(s => s.GetTypes())
            .Where(p => p.IsClass && p.IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClassA))).ToList();
```